# Docusign : How to know the originator of recipient event

Tags: docusignapi

We have single connect configured for all document/recipient events.

And if we have a document that is sent to 4-5 recipients with no signing order in place.Each time a recipient signs, the 'Recipient Signed' event is triggered.

But, there is no info as to how to identify which recipient has exactly triggered the event??

Currently, DocuSign connect sends the xml response with all the Recipients' status.

Answer (score 0):

Correct, if you want to know what has changed to cause a connect message to be sent to you, then you need to compare the latest message with the prior one.

Note that there can be more than one reason for a single connect message to be sent. Eg, when the last signer recipient signs, his status will be changed as well as the overall envelope status.